# ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification not being triggered in ios5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I had implemented the `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification` in ios4 and it worked perfectly, however now in ios5 it seems it's getting ignored. I add:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification) name: ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:self.library];
```

in my view controller initializer and in dealloc I put:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:nil];
```

Then the methdod implementation itself is:

```
- (void) ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification
{
//doSomeStuff

}
```

I need to add it in the initializer and remove it in dealloc so it updates if the user changes the library while out of the app. Anyone know a good solution to this?

Comment: It's an [iOS5's bug](http://www.openradar.me/10484334). Therefore we must do a workaround described in the link I wrote.

Answer (score 4):

I think that he meant to say:

1. Call [self.assetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:nil metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) { }]; immediately after creating instance of ALAssetsLibrary
2. Observe **ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification** (not NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification)